# IntelliJ Idea - resource SQL files not being copied to target

Tags: intellij-idea

I have some problems with IntelliJ Idea not copying SQL resource files into target directory, so I have to copy them there manualy.

I have SQL reosurce pattern in project's compiler settings.

I have standart structure maven project - with /etc/ folder holding property files which gets copied without problem. /etc/ folder holds /sql/ folder which i need to be copied as well, but  it gets not copied at all. /etc/ folder is set as source folder.

My folder structure:

```
-etc
    -conf
        -sql
-src
    -main
    -test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine, but could be a bug specific to your configuration. Could you please [submit an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with a sample project and pom.xml?